# 3by3 thread synchronization : how to avoid overhead

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, pthreads

Let's say I'm running N threads.
Every thread needs to be sync with the next and the previous one.

```
    for (i = 0 ; i < NITER; i++){
      do_something ();
      sync_with_neighbours (tId - 1, tId + 1);
    }
```

I need to implement the synchronization in the most efficient way.
Pthread barriers are not efficient as this way every thread will wait for the slowest one to reach the barrier.

Any idea will be welcome

EDIT:

No we don't have to wait for thread 0:

If those 2 neighbour threads , "i + 1" and "i - 1", are ready then thread "i" will run.

Let's say that we are running 6 threads with this situation at time T:

- th0: pending (running iter = m )
- th1: pending (running iter = m )
- th2: ready   (wait )
- th3: ready   (wait )
- th4: ready   (wait )
- th5: pending (running iter = m )

Situation at T + 1 will be:

- th0: pending (running iter = m )
- th1: pending (running iter = m )
- th2: ready   (wait )
- th3: running iter = m + 1
- th4: ready   (wait )
- th5: pending (running iter = m )

So as you can see there is no need for everybody to wait for Th0

Answer (score 3):

I assume (following your example) that you mean by syncronization no real rendenzvous, but cross-wise signaling. Thus, any thread can run if it gets a free signal by each neighbour.
For this purpose, you can use semaphors, one for each thread. 
The sync section looks like that:

```
   UP(left_sem)
   UP(right_sem)
   DOWN(own_sem,2)
```

(the first and the last thread have no left or right neighbour, resp. Thus, they need only a simple `DOWN`)

Regarding the implementation: classical System V semaphors seem to be appropriate, since the System V system calls deals already with arrays of semaphores, thus you only need do some indexing.
However, each kind of semaphore should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun - you can check out my game-of-life coding example -

http://parallel.cc/cgi-bin/bfx.cgi/test_cases.html

but since you don't have ParC, and are stuck with pThreads it's a bit tricky. The fastest way to synchronize is usually to use a simple semaphore mechanism where the (p)thread stays hot and just reads a memory location until it changes (e.g. wait for it to be non-zero).

Things to bear in mind:

If you separate data and semaphores such that the writes through the memory subsystem are not atomic and/or ordered stuff may not work (sometimes), so at a minimum make sure everything is on the same cache-line if possible, otherwise checksum your data so the receiving side knows it has a complete set of data.

Note 1: I'm presuming you mean "speed" rather than "efficiency" and you have as many cores as threads.

Note 2: pThreads grew out of OS-level multithreading (coarse) and just sucks at this level (fine).

Answer (score 0):

One approach may pass by using the library OpenMP (this library also use pthreads), and use the [ordered clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3f31k66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> In the execution of a for or parallel for construct with an ordered
>   clause, ordered constructs are executed strictly in the order in which
>   they would be executed in a sequential execution of the loop.

If I correctly understand your question thread 8 must sync with 7 and 9, but 7 must sync with 6 and 8 and so on, so in reality every thread must wait for thread zero. As soon thread zero is ready, thread 1 can also be ready and so on. So it looks like a situation each ordered clause may be useful.